# SoundMiner Relink Spotting List files

Tags: sfx, soundminer, database, spotting

I've been using SM spotting lists for a couple of years, creating folders with different categories of sounds that span across multiple databases.

I've recently moved my SFX library to a new drive, rescanned it and recreated my main libraries. My old spotting list folders are still linking to the old drive and will not open anymore. Is there any way to recover/relink these lists as you do with Relink Selected under a normal database?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

I located the ~/Library/Application Support/Soundminer/Spotting folder and replaced all the OLD FX DRIVE PATHS with "NEW DRIVE NAME" with textwrangler on all relevant smpotting.xxx files. My lists with all relevant selections are back!